# Matching a value to an item taken from a dropdown list

Tags: google-sheets

I've got a particular problem that I'm hoping someone can help me solve. I'm using Google Sheets to build a character sheet for a roleplaying game. As part of the sheet, players can choose equipment from a dropdown list. The items in this list, and their related data, have been imported into the sheet already using IMPORTRANGE from another sheet that acts as a global database.

In this example, the player can choose from a list of weapons. The data also includes the weapon's attack power. There are thus two columns here in the equipment sheet: one that contains a drop down list with the possible weapons the player can choose from, and one that should retrieve the chosen weapon's attack power. This data exists side by side in the sheet already, but I'm having trouble accessing it. How can I automatically populate the attack power cell with the correct value to match the chosen weapon from the dropdown list? This data already exists in the spreadsheet side by side in the correct order so it doesn't seem like it should be difficult, but I'm not really sure how to do it!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IaW0TKgFO1VLGo2W0YpVadNxU4zA2lKyr15RKIUoJHI/edit?usp=sharing Here you go. Ignore most of the values to the right, they'll be hidden when the sheet is ready for use. The imported data is contained in columns U and V - the weapon name and corresponding attack power. 

Under 'Equipment' you can see what I've currently got for the weapons, and just underneath it I've added what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try simple `VLOOKUP`:

```
=IFNA(VLOOKUP(N13, U:V, 2, 0))
```

[image]

and then you can multiply it with value you wish if needed

Comment: I just tried VLOOKUP myself and got it working, but your solution is a little more elegant I think, thanks!